# Is it not possible to have path parameter in the middle of a path w/ Gorilla Mux?

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I have the following API server snippets that create an endpoint, and I would like to abstract 'clusterID' as path parameter in the handler. Here's the router piece

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    sub := router.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()
    sub.Methods("GET").Path("/device/{clusterID}/job").HandlerFunc(authDev(getJob))
    ...
```

Below is a snippet of the handler. I get the vars as usual with `mux.Vars()`. If I send in a request to `localshost/api/v1/device/cluster123/job`, the handler gets called as expected, but `mux.Vars(r)` returns an empty map instead of returning a map with `clusterID=cluster123` as expected. Does Mux not support vars in the middle of the path? I know I can manually parse the path, but I expect Mux to do this for me.

```
func getJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    log.Println(params["clusterID"]) // outputs an empty string
    log.Println(params) // outputs an empty map
    ...
```

Comment: Can you post how authDev() looks and eventually try without it?

Comment: It's funny, I was thinking about that as I was comparing the solution from @mkopriva, which is almost identical to what I already had--accept the middleware auth function. Then, I read your question and a light went off and I remembered that I need to pass the route variables as context to the handler from the authorizer. Thanks. If you want to write that as a solution, I'd be happy to select it.

Comment: I think it's pretty much ok to either accept mkopriva's answer or even write your own explaining what was wrong and then self-accept it. I really didn't have answer here, just a hunch there's a problem with passing request/vars down to getJob() function from authDev().

Answer (score 6):

> Is it not possible to have path parameter in the middle of a path w/ Gorilla Mux?

Yes, it is.

> Does Mux not support vars in the middle of the path?

Yes, it does.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/device/{clusterID}/job", getJob)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}

func getJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Println(params["clusterID"])
    fmt.Println(params)
}
```

```sh
curl http://localhost:8000/device/123/job
```

Output:

```sh
123
map[clusterID:123]
```